# How can I solve the simple ratio in this exercise?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

I am studying proportions on my own, but how can I solve this exercise?

> In a kindergarten class, the value of the ratio between boys and girls is $3.5$. If the number of children is $140$, then how many girls are there?

What is the property or formula to solve this?

Comment: Set up a proportion? $\frac{7}{2} = \frac{140-x}{x}$ then cross multiply.

Comment: As Deepak commented, do you mean there are $3.5$ times as many boys as girls or $3:5$ so for every three boys there are five girls?  The approach is the same and both yield an answer that is not integral.

Comment: A slightly off-topic comment: "I am studying proportions on my own", what book are you reading on? Have you seen *similar* examples of such word problems?

Comment: The correct interpretation was 3.5 that is 7/2. so, (140 * 2)/7 = 40, that was the correct answer, sorry for my bad explanation and soo bad english.

Answer (score 1):

If there are $g$ girls there are $3.5g$ boys, so $$g+3.5g=140$$
Unfortunately, you have some fractional kids here.

Comment: And even another interpretation (the ratio as $3:5$) gives fractional kids.

Comment: "the value of the ratio" seems to me should me that $B:G = \frac BG = 3.5 = \frac 72 = 7:2$.  At least that is how I interpret it.  It wasn't clear.

Comment: @fleablood:  that is how I took it.

Answer (score 1):

I took "value of the ratio" is $3.5$ to mean that $\frac {\text {#number of boys}}{\text {#number of girls}} = 3.5$.

So if $g$ = number of girls and $b$ = number of boys we have:

$\frac bg = 3.5$ and $b + g = 140$.

$b = 3.5g$ so $3.5g + g = 140$

$4.5g = 140$

$9g = 280$

$g = \frac {280}9 = 31 \frac 19$ and $b = 108\frac 89$.

I'm assuming that the ratio being $3.5$ was a rounding estimation and that there are $31$ girls and $108$ boys.

So the actual ratio is $\frac {108}{31} \approx 3.5$.